# EF 5 Code First - Why is explicitly loaded data not accessible from my model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following two model objects which have a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class StaffMember
{
    public Guid StaffMemberKey {get; set;}
    // lots of other properties that aren't relevant

    public ICollection<Case> Cases {get; set;}
}

public class Case
{
    public int CaseKey {get; set;}
    // lots of other properties that aren't relevant

    public ICollection<StaffMember> Staff {get; set;}
}
```

The mapping for the many-to-many relationship is handled in the configuration for the Case entity:

```
public class CaseMapping :  EntityTypeConfiguration<Case>
{
    public CaseMapping()
    {
        // other property and relationship mappings

        // Many-to-Many mapping with Staff Members
        HasMany(c => c.Staff)
            .WithMany(staffMember => staffMember.Cases)
            .Map(m =>
                 {
                     m.ToTable("Cases_StaffMembers", "dbo");
                     m.MapLeftKey("CaseKey");
                     m.MapRightKey("StaffMemberKey");
                 });
    }
}
```

Everything is working great in terms of being able to query against this relationship, add, delete, etc. However, when trying to explicitly load and filter staff members for a case, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter), no data is being loaded in to the appropriate collection of related entities.

Here is an example of what I'm attempting do:

```
var staffMemberKey = Guid.Parse("...");
var caseKey = 5;

using (var context = new CodeFirstContext())
{
    var selectedCase = context.Cases.Find(caseKey);
    context.Entry(selectedCase).Collection(c => c.Staff).Query().Where(sm => sm.StaffMemberKey == staffMemberKey).Load();   
}
```

I would expect that `selectedCase.Staff` would contain the staff member that was loaded, but it remains null. If I call `ToList()` instead of `Load` when querying for the related data, the resulting list does contain the correct staff member entity. If I simply call `context.Entry(selectedCase).Collection(c => c.Staff).Load();`, then the data is loaded as expected. Is there something I'm missing? What gives?

As a final note, I have lazy loading and proxy creation disabled for my context, in case that makes any difference in this scenario.

Comment: The result of Query() are returned, not inserted into the collection.

Comment: Yes, but I'm calling `.Load()` on the `IQueryable` result which should load the resulting entities in to the context. From my understanding, this should make them available on my model, but perhaps this only works for one-to-many relationships and not many-to-many. I'm following the example from MSDN to a T, or trying to anyways...

Comment: It loads them into the EF context, but not into the property.

Comment: @CoryNelson: I understand that it is loading the objects in to the context but not populating the collection. However, I'm trying to understand why this is the case, whether this is normal behavior or a bug, or if I have done something incorrectly. I was able to do something very similar with a one-to-many relationship, and it seemed to work great.

Comment: Your collection properties are not virtual.

Comment: @Aron: Making the collection virtual doesn't make any difference. AFAIK, virtual navigation properties are intended for lazy loading, which I am not using.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Query()`, it returns an `IQueryable` that gives the entities that would be in that property -- it is not designed to be used to update the property. It is basically a "shortcut" for:

```
ctx.Staff.Where(staff => staff.Case.Id == caseKey);
```

`Load()` will load entities into your context, as if you had called `ToList()` but without returning anything. It works on any `IQueryable`, and does not capture anything related to the `Entry()`.

Comment: The problem is that loading related entities in the way I describe from the OP works great for 1-to-many relationships. For instance, I have a `Company` entity which has a 1-to-many relationship with staff members. I can call `ctx.Entry(company).Collection(c => c.Staff).Query().Where(sm => sm.StaffMemberKey == someKeyValue).Load();` and the loaded staff members are then available via `company.Staff`. It's only for many-to-many relationships that it doesn't seem to work the way I'm expecting it to.

Comment: How can you say EF is not designed that way, when MS provides documentation explicitly showing how to do exactly what I'm trying to do (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter)? As perviously stated, it also works great for one-to-many relationships

Comment: `DbCollectionEntry.Load` and `IQueryable.Load` are two different methods that do different things. I think this is where you're getting confused. Their documentation does not state that `IQueryable.Load()`, as you'd call by doing `Query().Load()`, will fill the property. If you can provide code for a one-to many relationship that exhibits contrary behavior I'd be interested to see it.